# Connect a client to a given server using Nodejs and Socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, client

I tried to write a client for a given server domain name as http://demo-chat-server.on.ag/. However, I can not connect my client to this server. My code is like this:

```
const io = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io.connect("http://demo-chat-server.on.ag/", {secure: true,    rejectUnauthorized: false});

socket.emit("connect", () => {
    console.log(socket.connected);
});

socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(socket.connected); // false
});
```

I received this 404 error from the console:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Also here is the task description:

[task description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SKdc.png)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest#comment459694_326569) . I've removed the "urgent" for you this time. Please don't use it again, thanks.

Comment: Anyway have you tried with https instead of http, just as a guess? 404 is hard for us to solve because we can't see the server to know what the correct URL is supposed to be, and you haven't provided any documenation which shows definitively what URL you should be using.

Comment: Hi,
In my task, it says: "The chat server itself can be accessed at https://demo-chat-server.on.ag/ " So I need to implement a web client for a https://socket.io chat server. Therefore I used Nodejs in VSC. To make a connection first I wrote npm init to bash. then I downloaded socket.io-client. Then I wrote the code above as a js file. And when I run the code, a script called launch.json has opened. So I added configuration into this script. To do this I wrote launch.json as:

Comment: '''
{    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "url": "https://demo-chat-server.on.ag/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/chat-client.js"
        }
    ]
}
'''

Comment: But I still see 'Cannot GET' from https://demo-chat-server.on.ag/ . And I really do not how to connect my client to this server

Comment: And sorry I may not have explained well.  So, I added the task description here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SKdc.png

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, error messages or data when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)